# Check if list contains unique elements or not

Tags: python, list, repeat

I want to check if a list is composed of unique elements.

For example: `[1,1,1]`, `[4,4,4,4]` or `[2]`.

List can contain any value but it must be unique throughout the list.

Comment: What have you tried? You should See the first value, then go through the rest until you find a different one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`set()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to get unique elements in the list and use **`len()`** to get the count of elements in your set. If it returns length as `1`, then you have only one unique element in your list:

```
>>> my_list = [1,1,1]
>>> len(set(my_list))
1
```

However above solution is not performance efficient. In case your list is huge, you should write your own function to check this efficiently as:

```
def is_unique(my_list):
       first_elem = my_list[0]
       for elem in my_list[1:]:
           if elem != first_elem:
               return False
       return True
```

Test runs:

```
>>> is_unique([1,1,2])
False

>>> is_unique([1,1,1])
True
```

Comment: That's the simplest solution and usually the best. Just for the record, it it much slower than manually checking in the case when the list is long and there are many different values.

Comment: @zvone Completely agree. Updated the answer per your suggestion